# What is the best practice to vertical align text within a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm struggling trying to do vertical align to one of my text field.

[image]

I want my chapter name `Integers and the Coordinate Plane` to place in the middle at my red line.

I've tried to use the vertical align, but I might have use it wrong.

Can someone please shed some lights on this ?

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/x34ot0o9/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row chapter-detail">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 no-padding ">
  <div class="ch-d-wrapper">
    <div class="ch-d-chapter ">CHAPTER</div>
    <div class="ch-d-num">6</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-11 no-padding ">
    <div class="ch-d-name">Integers and the Coordinate Plane</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**LESS**

```
.chapter-detail {

    border: solid #c9cacb 1px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    color: #293644;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    line-height: 38px;

    .ch-d-wrapper {
        text-align: center;
        border-right: solid #c9cacb 2px;
    }
    .ch-d-chapter{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .ch-d-num {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 35px

    }
    .ch-d-name {
        font-size: 23px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works with `.col-xs-8.col-sm-10.col-md-10.col-lg-11.no-padding { margin-top: 20px; }`.

Comment: @somethinghere - Why would `text-align: center` vertically center anything?

Comment: @somethinghere:  I know `text-align:center`  I want to vertical align. Did you even read my post before leave comment ?

Comment: He's even get 1 upvote for that comment, too. I'm surprise.

Comment: Text and line are not the same. Please, keep the question open. It will help people who have the same problem and are searching for "line" instead of "text".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 .ch-d-name {
        line-height:70px;  //added this.
        font-size: 23px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/x34ot0o9/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use different techniques, and I think they are equally valid.

1) If you know the height of the parent, simply use `line-height: "parent height"`

2) If you don't know the height of the parent, but you can set a line height at will then you could do: `line-height: 20px; margin-top: calc(50% - 10px);`

3) Table layout with vertical-align.

4) Flex layout with align-items: center

Answer (score 2):

`vertical-align` doesn't work in this way, as you might expect.

In this case, you can use margin or line-height to align the header. If you want a more reusable version, it's worth reading [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) about absolute vertical positioning.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGMrze?editors=110

```
.ch-d-name {
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```